# How to remove text highlight in combobox after I click alt + tab and when I come back to the same form in child form?

Tags: c#

I'm new to this forum. My C# project contains MDI parent and a child form. In My child form I've a combobox and I type some thing on it. Now the cursor will be at last position. When I move out off the form to different place (ex: My computer or any other application) by clicking alt + tab and when I come back to the same form, now the text in the dropdown is got selected. I do not want the text to get selected after I move away from the form and return back. I want the cursor to be at last position.

I've tried the following code in the form activated event, but still it doesn't work.

```
comboBox1.SelectionStart = comboBox1.Text.Length + 1;
```

Can any one help solving this?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: In c# indices are 0 (zero) based. So Length+1 will be out of bounds.

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow. This is not exactly a forum. Maybe you want to read [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Yes, I understand. I just wanted to place the cursor after the last char. That's the reason, I gave Length + 1.